# How can I allow users to join Google Meet without having to ask?

Tags: node.js, api, express, google-api

I'm scheduling a google meet based on specific time and date, and so far it's going well, it generates a google meet link. But the only problem is that I have to ask to join while no one is there to accept. Is there is a way to get around this? knowing that I get the emails of both of the participants.

I'm using a package called google-meet-api

This is the code:

```
 const meetingLink = await Meeting({
    clientId: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,
    refreshToken: process.env.REFRESH_TOKEN,
    date,
    time,
    summary: 'Interview',
    location: 'Online',
    description: 'Interview',
  });

  if (!meetingLink) {
    throw new CustomError('Error creating the meeting, please try again later', 500);
  }

console.log(meetingLink) // https://meet.google.com/arr-yrre-t**
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're the `primary` user or one of the invitees, then the URL should give you the option to "join the meeting" even if noone else (including the organizer) is present.

Without more details in your question, it's difficult to provide more help.

Are you using this NPM package: [google-meet-api](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-meet-api)?

The NPM package is an implementation of the Google SDK method and is little more than the [example](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/insert#examples) code that's provided by Google.

I encourage you to consider writing this code for yourself and saving yourself a mostly redundant depdendency on a 3rd-party NPM package that adds very little value.

The Google documentation page for the calendar [Events:insert](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/insert) method (which is what is being used by the `google-meet-api` package) provides details of the [parameters](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/insert#parameters) and the [request body](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/insert#request-body).

By reviewing the parameters and request body fields, you can confirm to yourself whether you're missing one of the fields that would address your problem.